# How to query MongoDb having array using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ff6d54f07a36271465441c"),
    "Author" : "John",
    "Content" : "Thera are alot of databases",
    "CreatedAtUtc" : ISODate("2016-04-02T06:57:24.542Z"),
    "Tags" : [ 
        "elasticSearch", 
        "MongoDb", 
        "C#"
    ],
    "Title" : "Best DB"
}
```

I like to find all documents which have tag: "MongoDb"

I tried:

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.In("Tags", "MongoDb");
var posts = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Where post is a C# class

But i get no documents. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying for documents where there is an equality match of "MongoDB" on the `Tags` array, just use the query document `{ "Tags": "MongoDb" }:`

**Mongo Shell**

```
db.collection.find({ "Tags": "MongoDb" })
```

**C#**

Use the **[`Eq`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinitionBuilder_1_Eq.htm)** method to implement a filter document that specifies an equality condition:

```
var filter = Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq("Tags", "MongoDb");
var posts = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
```

Comment: This actually resolves to `{ "Tags": ["MongoDB"] }` which not only does not match to any element in the list, but also does not match any "list" that does not "soley" contain the "MongoDB" property. I don't think you really know the answer and just found a post you thought you would copy.

Comment: Thanks chridam, it's really too simple!.